# unable to insert in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

i am trying to insert an element in the given linked list but when i want to print it its showing infinite loop.In insert() call i am passing the address of the pointer whereas in display i am only passing the address stored in the pointer. help me plz

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node{
int item;
node *ptr;
};
int insert(node **head, int data, int position)
{ 
int count=1;
node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->item=data;
temp->ptr=NULL;
node *p,*q;
p=*head;
if(*head==NULL)
{
    *head=temp;
}
if(position==1)
{
    temp->item=*head;
    *head=temp;
}
else{
while(p!=NULL&&count<position)
{
    count++;
    q=p;
    p=p->ptr;

}
q->ptr=temp;
temp->ptr=p;
}
}
void display(node *temp)
{
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf("the data is %d",temp->item);
    temp=temp->ptr;
}
}
void main()
{
node *head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
insert(&head,29,1);
display(head);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use malloc in C++. In fact this should probably be tagged as C instead.

Comment: Your formatting/indentation needs work.  Looks like your debugger skills are not forthcoming, either:(

Comment: Oh yeah... use C++ container classes instead.

Comment: What was your intention with `position`? What if the Linked List only had 2 elements and you passed in a position of 5? Would you want the element in between to become valid Nodes?

Comment: sorry its c file . assuming that we r passing a valid and in range value in position like if u have 2 elements, than the value passed in positions may be 1 or 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its a C Program please categorize properly.
2. No use of any C++ modules in your code.

Going with C implementation -

I think the double pointer is not required in a simple insert into a linked list.
You can do is -

```
void insert(node *head, int data){
   node *temp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->item = data;
   temp->ptr= NULL;
   if(head==NULL){  //empty list
       head=temp;
   }
   else {
     while(head->ptr!=NULL){ //traverse till end
       head=head->ptr;
     }
     head->ptr=temp;
   }
 }
```

And from main function call as insert(head,value);

Comment: You need a double pointer for when the list is empty (`head == NULL`). You're just assigning the local variable so `head` will still be `NULL` outside the function.

Comment: Sorry - " forgot to state ASSUMPTIONS - Assuming `head` is declared as global.."

Comment: But `head` is still a local variable that you are changing.

Comment: Ohh Yeah, what I should have done is copy the global `head` into `temp1` variable then traverse `temp1` variable and insert :) Thanks for reminding.

Comment: If you don't use double pointer than you have to write another function insert only for 1st element to insert, when the list is empty..

Comment: As I said I just gave a example code of insertion of one element into a linked list. (not the entire insert code!!)

Comment: 'void insert' >> 'node *insert'.  You can then assign to head.